# Number of change notifications thrown when sorting an ObservableList

Tags: java, javafx

I was playing around with JavaFX, stumbled across Oracle's [Using JavaFX Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/collections-tutorial/collections.htm#JFXCL107) tutorial, and ran into a question. In Example 1-6 they use `FXCollections` to sort an `ObservableList`:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("d");
list.add("b");
list.add("a");
list.add("c");

ObservableList<String> observableList = FXCollections.observableList(list);
observableList.addListener(new ListChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change change) {
        System.out.println("Detected a change! ");
    }
});

FXCollections.sort(observableList); // one notification, as expected
// Collections.sort(observableList); // also only one notification. why?
```

According to the tutorial, only one change notification is printed out. The tutorial mentions that there will be four change notifications when `Collections.sort()` is used instead of `FXCollections.sort()`, but I still get only one. Any ideas why? What needs to be done to get four change notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `SortableList` API (can't seem to find the javadoc online):

> SortableList is a list that can sort itself in an efficient way, in
>   contrast to the Collections.sort() method which threat all lists the
>   same way. E.g. ObservableList can sort and fire only one notification.

Essentially:

- You invoke `FXCollections.sort` on your `ObservableList`, which descends from `SortableList`
- `FXCollections.sort` will cast your `ObservableList` to `SortableList`, and invoke `((SortableList<? extends T>)list).sort();`
- The concrete type seems to be `com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper`
- In turn, that operation claims to fire only **1** notification upon sort

**Note (I)**: source for JDK8u45 for `FXCollections.sort` here...

```
/**
 * Sorts the provided observable list.
 * Fires only <b>one</b> change notification on the list.
 * @see Collections#sort(java.util.List)
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(ObservableList<T> list) {
    if (list instanceof SortableList) {
        ((SortableList<? extends T>)list).sort(); // here's what happens
    } else {
        List<T> newContent = new ArrayList<T>(list);
        Collections.sort(newContent);
        list.setAll((Collection<T>)newContent);
    }
}
```

**Note (II)**: source for `ObservableListWrapper.sort`...

```
@Override
public void sort(Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
    if (backingList.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    int[] perm = getSortHelper().sort(backingList, comparator);
    // here's the single change fired
    fireChange(new SimplePermutationChange<E>(0, size(), perm, this));
}
```

As you can see, the `fireChange` invocation triggers **once**, after the sort is actually performed.

**Update**

The `Collections.sort` idiom invokes `List.sort`. 
In Java 8, `List.sort` actually has a `default` implementation, but it's not used here as it's overridden, so the mechanism in place is still from `ObservableListWrapper`.

**TL;DR**

I doubt there's any elegant way to get as many notifications as the number of operations it takes to sort the `List`, unless you use your own implementation of `ObservableList`.

**Quick trick!** (tested in Java 8)

I just found a trick to actually trigger multiple `Changed` events.

If you use the following idiom:

`Collections.sort(observableList.subList(0, observableList.size()));`

The reason is that `subList` will return a `List`, hence the `default` `List.sort` will be used.

Comment: Thanks for your deliberations, it gives insights in how `FXCollections.sort()` works and why `FXCollections.sort()` triggers only one change notification. But the question is why `Collections.sort()` also triggers only one change notification (instead of four, as mentioned in Oracle's tutorial).

Comment: @Roland didn't see that edit, it must have come after I answered. I'll take a look.

Comment: @Roland see my edit and a quick trick to actually trigger the multiple change notifications.

Comment: Isn't `Collections.sort()` supposed to work the same way, no matter what type of `List` it gets? Somehow I don't see why it makes a difference whether a `List` or a `SortableList` is passed as parameter.

Comment: @Roland read my answer: `Collections.sort` invokes `List.sort`. In Java 8, this is a `default` implementation (whereas before Java 8 the virtual invocation would resolve to the concrete class). Here it's overridden by `ObservableListWrapper` anyway, so `Collections.sort` and `FXCollections.sort` do exactly the same thing!

Comment: You can use the `Collections.sort(observableList.subList(0, observableList.size()));` trick if you really really want the listener to trigger multiple times, but that is likely not optimized.